# How to dynamically scale icecast server ? ( with multiple dynamic mount points )

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, icecast

i'm trying to have a cluster of icecast servers and i would like it to scale "dynamically" ( in a elastic beans talk fashion ), but i can't find any resources regarding this issue.

The scenario would be:

- Mountpoints can be created/deleted at any time
- A master would run on a "more powerful" EC2 instance
- Have a cluster of "relays" under AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Configure Elastic Beanstalk to tear up/down relays based on bandwidth metrics

Questions:

- Is there a recommended way to scale it dynamically? 
  ( let's say we get a high peak on weekend and then almost no users on monday )
- Is there any affordable service that would relay my dynamic mount ? 
  ( let's say we would then just have 1 huge EC2 machine, and have this service as our relays )

Apologises for such open ended question, i can't be very precise at the moment as i still didn't find any clear way to take this further.

Comment: I offer Icecast-compatible hosting with a configuration that supports what you are trying to achieve.  It isn't Icecast, but my own creation, AudioPump.  If you're interested, feel free to e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.  It isn't publicly available yet but has been in use by a small handful of companies for awhile now.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are overestimating the resource consumption of the icecast server.
[There are load tests you should read.](http://icecast.org/loadtest/)

You only need significant CPU cycles if you want to also run the source clients yourself AND if those have to encode your content on the fly. If you have pre-encoded content, then also source clients will scale without problem on one machine.

I personally think EC2 is not well suited for a complex setup including source clients with lots of files. It will almost always be more expensive than a traditional VPS or even small root server.

Comment: I'll just host the server, each mount point will be broadcasted from a different machine which will take care of the encoding.